# Which local folder does ios dropbox to save?

Tags: storage, local

I want to know, how to save file to local storage. Like dropbox for iOS and many other similar app. 
I read the Apple Document, we can save file to cache and tmp, I want to save to local storage for ever, so the files in cache and tmp folder will be removed by system.
How does dropbox to save in the local storage?

I want to develop a app, encrypt file, then save to local.  We can not save to Document, because apple will reject.

I have no idear, where to save.

Comment: If you have found the answer to your query, plz share it

Comment: We can save in document folder, and prevent these files from being backed up to iCloud and iTunes.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011342